# Disable chrome pop up "Leaving Site? Changes you made may not be saved"

Tags: jquery, alert

My web application is built with .NET MVC and Jquery.

On Chrome browser, while clicking on the button, I'm getting this alert:

> Leaving Site? Changes you made may not be saved.  Leave cancel button
>   appeared

I want to disable this pop up.

I've tried this but it doesn't solve the goal.

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```
$(window).off('beforeunload.windowReload');
```

however its not recommended.

Comment: Hi Moh, Thank you for the input. But unfortunately, above code also not working :(

Comment: Have you included jquery ?

Comment: yes i included but no luck. Later I tried below code and it worked.
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
Thank you for your help.